# unbalanced stack because of pointer

Tags: c#, c++, pointers, pinvoke

I'm not sure how to resolve this problem and I have been hitting my head against a brick wall for the best part of two hours. I have a function in an unmanaged DLL with the following documentation:

```
BOOL ZLNET_QueryDeviceTime(LONG lLoginID, LPZLNET_TIME pDeviceTime, int waittime=2000);
```

I assume that the `pDeviceTime` is a pointer and therefore I pass out in my C# code in order to use as a reference.
In my C# project I have the following declaration:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct ZLNET_TIME
    {
        public Int32 dwYear;
        public Int32 dwMonth;
        public Int32 dwDay;
        public Int32 dwHour;
        public Int32 dwMinute;
        public Int32 dwSecond;
    } ;

[DllImport("zlnetsdk.dll")]
unsafe public static extern bool ZLNET_QueryDeviceTime(long lLoginID, out ZLNET_TIME pDeviceTime, int waittime);
```

The I call my function:

```
ZLNET_TIME t = new ZLNET_TIME();
ZLNET_QueryDeviceTime(loginResult, out t, 2000);
```

However, when I run my project I get the error:

> Managed Debugging Assistant `PInvokeStackImbalance` has detected a problem in (MY APP EXE).
>
> Additional Information: A call to `PInvoke` function `VP::ZLNET_QueryDeviceTime` has unbalanced the stack. This is likely because the managed `PInvoke` signature does not match the unmanaged target signature. Check that the calling convention and parameters of the PInvoke signature match the target unmanaged signature."

I then get nothing back in my `ZLNET_TIME` variable. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Neither side looks like you're using a pointer. What is the definition of `LPZLNET_TIME` on the C++ side? Is it a typedef?

Comment: Why out rather than ref?

Comment: The first argument is not *long*, it is *int*.  And you probably need to use the CallingConvention property.  The description is vague but as shown it should be Cdecl.

Comment: Your struct is using Int32 objects.  Likely these will get marshaled correctly, but you should really just use 'int' which is a 32 bit int by definition.

Comment: How is the native ZLNET_TIME defined?

Comment: Why are you assuming? just check

Answer (score 0):

The first parameter should be int rather than long in the C# code. On the C++ side long is a 32 bit type. But in C# it is 64 bits.

The other potential issue is calling convention. Are you sure the C++ code is stdcall? It looks like it is cdecl unless you omitted the code that specifies the calling convention.